# Use Realm's non-persistant properties in new RLMArray

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to use Realm with an ignored property. Actually much like in this article 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/81615/introduction-to-realm
`distance` which is declared as a model property but is actually not persisted and used temporarily to be calculated and displayed.

And then I have something like this

```
func calculateDistance(stops:RLMResults) -> RLMArray {
    let currentLocation = getCurrentLocation()
    var results:RLMArray = RLMArray(objectClassName: Stop.className())
    for (var i = 0; i < Int(stops.count); i++) {
        var stop = stops[UInt(i)] as Stop
        let stopLocation = CLLocation(latitude: stop.coordinates.latitude, longitude: stop.coordinates.longitude)
        let distance = currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(stopLocation)
        if kDistanceMeters >= distance {
            println("Distance to \(stop.stopName) --> \(distance) m ---- max(\(Int(kDistanceMeters))")
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            stop.distance = Double(distance)
            results.addObject(stop)
            realm.commitWriteTransaction()
            println(stop.distance) // Prints out the distance. It's in the object
        }
    }
    println("Getting the results")
    println(results) // Distance property isn't there ...
    return results
}
```

Basically I'd like to use this new temporary `results` RLMArray to display only the results I want in the view, with `distance` property.
The property is actually assigned on the object, but once in the RLMArray it disappears. I'm not getting any errors btw.

I also read on stackoverflow that ignored properties of Realm should not be used like that.. so what be a proper solution to my problem getting results into an array with additional property added? Converted to a normal object?

Answer (score 0):

For now you will need to create your own NSArray of objects sorted by closest distance. You can only query on persisted properties right now.